# Can RethinkDB efficiently handle lots of sparseness?

Tags: schema, rethinkdb

usecase: as part of a data-infra I'm contemplating storing many* entities of various [schema.org](http://schema.org/) types in the same RethinkDB table.

Given the inherent type-hierarchy of schema.org, some properties are shared by all types, some properties are only available on 1 type, and everything in between.

For example: a [Person](http://schema.org/Person),[Organization](http://schema.org/Organization),[LocalBusiness](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), share properties like `name`, `description`, `postalAddress`, etc. while some are only used by Person, such as `firstName`.

Mapping this to a RethinkDB table will result in many properties (fields in Rethink-speak) being empty for many entities. As a guess I'd say a field will be empty about 90% of the time on average. About ~150 fields exist.

Would RethinkDB be able to efficiently handle such a sparse layout? This is a broad question I realize, but I'm looking for specifics like:

- If I were to build indexes on some (not all) of these fields would empty values consume space in these indexes?
- what would the performance penalty (cpu and mem) be if these fields were all allowed to be multivalued? i.e.: arrays?

*) a couple of million to start with

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB works well with sparse data.  Indexes are currently always sparse indexes, so your index won't be cluttered up by documents that don't have the indexed field.